# Load jpg file in winapi

Tags: winapi, jpeg

I want to load a jpg file. I tried to use the `LoadImage` function but it returns `NULL` if my image is not bmp. What can I do? Here is my code:

```
hBitmap =(HBITMAP)LoadImage(0, L"D:\\1.jpg", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at WIC.

> [Windows Imaging Component (WIC) API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719654(VS.85).aspx) enables applications to work with all common image formats. It allows developers to not have to understand intricate details of the image formats they work with. WIC has built-in support for popular formats such as JPEG, PNG, TIFF, and GIF as well as an extensibility model so that developers can create their own WIC decoder and encoder (CODEC) and get platform level support for their image format. WIC is available on Windows XP (SP2 and greater), Windows Vista, Windows Server, and Windows 7.

Comment: The WIC API is outrageously complex, opaque and twisted. A great Microsoft masterpiece... I wonder if some people are really using this...

Answer (score 2):

Use GDI+, it has a JPEG decoder.  Start that ball rolling with #include `<gdiplus.h>` and a [small tutorial](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=gdiplus+tutorial&aq=0&aqi=g1&oq=gdiplus+tu&fp=cbc2f75bf9d43a8f) to know how to use the Image class and GdiplusStartup properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support really old stuff (Win9x etc,) IPicture / [OleLoadPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693724%28VS.85%29.aspx) is your best bet